# Can I control whether gcc places exception-throwing code inside/outside the main body of a function?

Tags: exception, gcc

Consider this:

```
void test_throwing_function ()
{
    if (0 == function_1 ())
        throw std::logic_error (__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    function_2 ();
}
```

I compiled this on GCC (a debug build, no optimisations) and, in abbreviated pseudo-machine-code, the result was this

```
call function_1
test result, 0
jne do_not_throw
call allocate_exception
call std::logic_error::logic_error
call throw_exception
label do_not_throw:
call function_2
return
```

An alternative implementation would look like this

```
call function_1
test result, 0
je do_throw
call function_2
return
label do_throw:
call allocate_exception
call std::logic_error::logic_error
call throw_exception
```

The optimized build appears to use the second approach, as I would have expected.

I have code which throws many exceptions, and I would also like to be able to read the machine code in the debugger without seeing the exception throwing junk mixed into the normal flow.

Is there a way to tell gcc to use the second implementation method in a non-optimized build?

Answer (score 0):

No, there doesn't seem to be a way to tell gcc to do this reordering at `-O0`. It is controlled by the `-freorder-blocks` flag:

```
$ g++ -O 1.c -S -o- | egrep '(ret|call.*logic_error)'
        ret
        call    _ZNSt11logic_errorC1EPKc@PLT
```

and with `-fno-reorder-blocks` we get the `-O0` behavior:

```
$ g++ -O -fno-reorder-blocks 1.c -S -o- | egrep '(ret|call.*logic_error)'
        call    _ZNSt11logic_errorC1EPKc@PLT
        ret
```

But the flag only has effect if optimizations are enabled. Here is the relevant portion from `gcc/bb-reorder.c` (the `gate` method of a pass tells whether or not it is executed):

```
  virtual bool gate (function *)
    {
      if (targetm.cannot_modify_jumps_p ())
        return false;
      return (optimize > 0
              && (flag_reorder_blocks || flag_reorder_blocks_and_partition));
    }
```

And indeed, passing `-freorder-blocks` without `-O[123s]` has no effect.

AFAIK, this is the case for most optimization passes. I don't know if there's a reason for not allowing the user to have this particular optimization at `-O0`. You could try tweaking the code above and building a custom version of gcc to find out ;-)

Also, there might be a way of tricking gcc into producing the code you want, but I don't have any idea on how to do that.